# Find a general solution of the reducible second-order differential equation

Tags: calculus

$$yy'' + (y')^2 = yy'$$

So I make my obvious $p$ substitutions:

$$y' = p$$
$$y'' = p(dp/dy)$$

Then:

$$yp(dp/dy) + p^2 = yp$$

Then I know I can reduce this equation to use the integrating factor, so:

$$dp/dy + p/y = 1$$

Where: $$I(x) = e^\int(1/y)dy$$
$$I(x) = y$$

And:

$$y(dp/dy) = 1(y)$$
$$py = (y^2)/2$$

And this is where I get lost. I don't know what the correct next step is, and I end up with convoluted answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to do it. Note that

$${\left( {yy'} \right)^\prime } = yy'' + {\left( {y'} \right)^2}$$

hence your equation becomes

$${\left( {yy'} \right)^\prime } = yy'$$

which results in

$$yy' = C{e^x}$$

but again you can notice that

$${1 \over 2}{\left( {{y^2}} \right)^\prime } = yy'$$

and hence you have

$${\left( {{y^2}} \right)^\prime } = 2C{e^x}$$

Integrating once more leads to

$${y^2} = 2C{e^x} + B$$

Answer (score 1):

(To answer the question where to go next - as opposed to the great method outlined by H.R) You were close 
$$
yp = \int y dy = \frac{y^2}{2}+C 
$$
please be careful with notation and doing operations simultaneously on left and right of the equals sign. e.g.
$$
p\mathrm{e}^{\int \frac{1}{y}dy} = \int 1\cdot \mathrm{e}^{\int \frac{1}{y}dy}
$$
not
$$
y\dfrac{dp}{dy} = 1\cdot y
$$
(back to the question)
$$
p\mathrm{e}^{\int \frac{1}{y}dy} = \int 1\cdot \mathrm{e}^{\int \frac{1}{y}dy} = \int y dy = \frac{y^2}{2}+C
$$
(this is probably where you forgot the constant along other things)
$$
\frac{yy'}{y^2+2C} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
let $y^2+2C = v$ we find
$$
\frac{v'}{2v} = \frac{1}{2}\implies \ln v = x + C_1
$$
so we have
$$
v = A\mathrm{e}^x = y^2+2C
$$
or
$$
y^2 = A\mathrm{e}^x - 2C
$$

Comment: I'm having trouble where you got:

$$yy′/((y^2)+2c)  = 2$$ 

Can you explain?

Comment: No need to worry that you don't understand how i got there..as neither do I! I made a mistake at that point..so you are correctly having issues there. It is meant to be a $1/2$ on thr r.h.s. You did all the hard work.

Comment: Woops I meant the whole derivation of that equation, not just the r.h.s. For some reason I can't logically see the progression to getting the l.h.s. you have.